# Как при помощи input file поменять значение переменной?

Tags: html, javascript

Подскажите, как при помощи `input type=file` поменять значение переменной F?

```
<script src="http://criuleni.do.am/media/?
auto=1;small=0;color=222222;loop=0;textoff=0;
t=audio;
f=адрес файла"
type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

Comment: Уточните ваш вопрос, что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: ....не думаю что понижение репутации мне чем то может помочь....

Comment: Всё понятно.Вопросов больше нет.Всем Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Не измените вы путь загружаемого файла, если ваша цель именно это.

Answer (score 0):

> > f=адрес файла ...

Никак, да и что это вам даст? Если вы про локальный путь.